# Dependent qualified name lookup in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, overload-resolution

This is about dependent name lookup in a template function, for example:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T const &t)
{
    ::func(t);
}
```

In this code, `func` is a dependent name because it has a type-dependent expression as argument to a function call. In C++11 the lookup for `func` was covered by [temp.dep.candidate]/1:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1) or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

[Note: 3.4.1 is "ordinary" unqualified-id lookup, and 3.4.2 is unqualified-id lookup for function names, aka. ADL, and 3.4.3 is qualified-id lookup].

However in C++14 (N3936) the parts about *qualified-id* lookup were removed:

> For a function call where the *postfix-expression* is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

Assuming that this change was done on purpose; which clauses now cover the finding of candidate functions for a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name and a qualified-id ?

(Background: I am looking for confirmation that qualified name lookup still only looks in the template definition context, not the instantiation context).

Comment: Which draft are you using for C++14, b/c `N3936` does not read like that.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that draft as well please?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour fixed. I thought I'd copy-paste to avoid having to do all the quote/bulletpoint formatting again, but made a mess of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defect report [1321](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3367.html#1321) has been accepted into the latest C++14 draft (N4140). This defect report clarifies the equivalency of dependent names, and at the same time clarifies that a dependent name must be an *unqualified-id*. Formerly, in C++11, dependent names could be arbitrary *id-expression*s.

This means that *qualified-id* names are no longer dependent names, and are therefore looked up according to §14.6.3 [temp.nondep]. This doesn't actually affect program behaviour from C++11, since dependent names only affect whether ADL (§3.4.2) is performed with the template instantiation context, and only *unqualified-id*s are eligible for ADL anyway.

Comment: [There's more detailed discussion of DR1321 in N4193, Revision 91 if the CWG issues list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4193.html#1321).

Comment: @nneonneo `This doesn't affect program behavior from C++11`. I don't understand this. In C++11 it was possible to execute a qualified name lookup from the template definition context, for a function call dependent on a template parameter. Now in C++14, this is not possible! How come this doesn't affect program behavior from C++11?